Connecting to an OPC UA Server with asyncua Using Encryption Without a Pre-Existing Certificate
How can I use Python asyncua to create a connection to the server encrypted with Basic128Rsa15 and Sign if I don't have the certificate? Is there a method to force the client to fetch the certificate itself and add it to the trust list?
    client = Client(url=url)
    client.set_user("Op")
    client.set_password("Op")
    client.set_security_string("Basic128Rsa15,Sign") 
    client.create_session()
    try:
        await client.connect()
    except Exception:
        _logger.exception('Connect:'+'error')


See https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/examples/client-with-encryption.py to create a certificate for your client

You can't fetch a certificate, because the certificate must be create for your application uri and hostname/ip.

I am facing an issue with the asyncua library. When using the set_security() or set_security_string() functions, I need to provide the path to a certificate and a private key, both of which I do not have.
Is there a way to generate these automatically and trust them, similar to how Softing does it?

Look at the example https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/examples/client-with-encryption.py
